# Excel; search column one to find data in column 2?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't figure out the search terms to look this up. Maybe somebody has a clue.

I have got 2 columns of data. I want to search the first column for a value, such as `0` for amount of earthquakes that day. In column two is the amount of rain on the corresponding day.

What I want is a list of amounts of rain on days when there was no earthquakes. So I need to search the earthquake column for all `0`'s and returns the rain amount values, such as `1` for one inch, which is in the column next to the earthquake amounts

Comment: This site is not a script / formula writing service. There is a reasonable expectation here for the person asking to have attempted something prior to posting the question. Please take a look at ***[ask]***, then update your question with more details.

Comment: Search for `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH`, `IF`, `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in columns **A** and **B**

[image]

, apply an AutoFilter to column **A** to display only **0**s

to get:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, you just made my day so much simpler